# Rails make exception in the application.html.erb

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I want to create a login file in my Ruby On Rails but when I do that I get my `navbar` which I have created above the `<%= yield %>` element, how can I make an exception for the `login.html.erb` file so it doesn't have a `navbar`?

Comment: Are you using `devise` ?

Answer (score 2):

Move your navbar to partial, and render partial conditionally:

```
<!-- _nav_bar.html.erb -->
<div class="nav"> ... </div>

<!-- application.html.erb -->
<% unless @skip_navbar %>
  <%= render partial: 'nav_bar' %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your controller set the condition variable:

```
def login
  @skip_navbar = true
  # ...
end
```

Comment: He puts on every page two navbars I solved that with putting @skip_navbar = true on every controller, but at the login he isn't gone.

Comment: You should also change all of your `app/views/layouts/*.html.erb`, not just `application.html.erb`. Did you do that?